# Spring MVC HandlerInterceptor : Redirect Failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, handler

I have created a simple WebMVC application - with handler interceptor configured. The interceptors responsibility is simple - it should check if a valid session exists in the HttpRequest - and if this is true, redirect to a registration page.

The issue i encounter is that on redirect - the browser is throwing the message:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

The interceptors code is as follows:

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{



// to be used checking session management for user.
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         Object handler) throws Exception {


    System.out.println(" <interceptor> - this is pre handle");

    return true;
}


@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                       ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(" <interceptor> - this is post handle");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");


    System.out.println(" <interceptor> - session id is --> " + session.getId());
    System.out.println(" <interceptor> - session create time is --> " + session.getCreationTime());
    System.out.println(" <interceptor> - session last accessed time is --> " + session.getLastAccessedTime());

    try {
        System.out.println(" <interceptor> - user info is --> " + user.toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.toString();
    }

    try{
        if(session != null){
            response.sendRedirect("register");
            return;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.toString();
    }

}


public void afterCompletetion(){
    System.out.println(" <interceptor> - this is after completion");

}
```

}

I have attempted to append the full request context path to the redirect - as well as the root context - both of which fail. I cannot see where I am failing on this - so any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it is just a C&P issue... but check the last method ... you misspelled it.. public void afterCompletetion(){ should be public void afterCompletion(){ and don't forget to use @Override, you'd found the issue yourself...

Comment: Change to `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/register");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever the interceptor you have written will come into picture for all requests.

So when it will redirect to `/register` that time also it will reach interceptor it will find that `session` is not null and again redirect..and same thing continues...**infinite redirection to same request.**

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                       ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception { 
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
    try{
        if(session != null){                            //Infinite 
            response.sendRedirect("register");
            return;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.toString();
    }

}
```

So Make sure that it will intercept for only one request by `configuration` or by `code`

```
if((request.getRequestURI().equals(contextPath+"/someURI") && session != null){
    response.sendRedirect("register");
}
```

Then it will check only for particular request and redirect to register.It wont fell in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check your interceptors configuration to see if its accepting only certain url pattern.

See the example below.

```
<!-- Configures Interceptors -->
<mvc:interceptors>
     <!-- This XML will intercept all URIs -->
     <bean class="com.howtodoinjava.interceptor.DemoInterceptor"></bean>

     <!-- This XML will apply interceptor to only certain URIs -->
     <!--
     <mvc:interceptor>
          <mvc:mapping path="/users"></mvc:mapping>
          <bean class="com.howtodoinjava.interceptor.DemoInterceptor"></bean>
     <mvc:interceptor>
      -->
</mvc:interceptors>
```